# How to access a variable from an asynchronous function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want to read a variable defined outside an asynchronous function.
But the console tells me that my variable is not defined.
`selectors is not defined`

How can I solve this or what am I not understanding ?

File 1 : index.js

```
import { getSpecs } from "./getSpecs.js";

let file = fs.readFileSync('selectors.json');
let selectors = JSON.parse(file);
await getSpecs(selectors);
```

File 2 : getSpecs.js

```
export let getSpecs = async function(selectors)
{
    var1 = document.querySelector(selectors.seller).innerText;
    ....
}
```

Comment: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `var1` in `getSpecs` because they are not declared in the same [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures.).

Comment: Yes, this is true. However you could export that variable, but exporting it and importing to the other file will result in circular dependency. You shouldnt do that. Create a file that exports an object with a property, and import it that object. With that you will be able to modify the property.

Answer (score 1):

The scope for a variable declared without `var`/`let`/`const` for a module is *that module* and not the global environment.

Don't use globals. Return the value you care about instead.

```
import { getSpecs } from "./getSpecs.js";

let var1 = 1;
const var1 = await getSpecs();
```

File 2 : getSpecs.js

```
export async function getSpecs()
{
    const var1 = 2;
    return var1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will modify the value and return other value, wouldn't it be better to send the value as a parameter to the function?

```
import { getSpecs } from "./getSpecs.js";

let var1 = 1;
let newVar1 = await getSpecs(var1);
```

File 2 : getSpecs.js

```
export async function getSpecs(var1)
{
    const response = var1 + 2;
    return response;
}
```

Like that?